# Cambiar el tamaño del buscador de un datable?

Tags: datatables

Quiero aumentar el ancho del buscador de mi datatable, ya intente de todo pero no me genera el cambio, mi código es el siguiente:

```
div.dataTables_filter {
    width: 100px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenida a SO. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que conozcas la forma de elaborar una pregunta que sea bien recibida por la comunidad.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la parte que debes editar en tu `CSS` es esta:

```
div.dataTables_wrapper div.dataTables_filter input {
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
}
```

Por defecto el `width` está en `auto`. Cámbialo por el tamaño que requieras.

Answer (score 0):

Saludos podrias hacer algo como esto con Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {             
  $('.dataTables_filterinput[type="search"]').css(
     {'width':'350px','display':'inline-block'}
  );
});
```

En este caso establesco el **width** a "350px" espero te ayude y suerte.

Referencia: [Change size input search Datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18816229/how-can-we-change-width-of-search-fields-in-datatables)